# table/search path with subdirectories

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have tons of CSV-files wich I like to use to create hundreds of plots. I organized the files in subdirectories to my plots directory.
I set the table search path like this:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        table/search path={plots/},
    }
```

But neither lualatex nor xelatex searches the subdirectories. Is there a way to tell lualatex to search subdirectories to?

Comment: if the files are in your TEXINPUTS path then they should be found just referencing the local filename from tex so `TEXINPUTS=:// luatex main-document` should find files in any level of subdirectory below the current directory

Comment: Don't know why, but it doesn't work for me. I'm running a texlive and it still ends with an error message.

Comment: probably didn't help that I mistyped the path syntax, should be  `TEXINPUTS=.//:`  or whatever syntax you need on your command line shell to set an environment variable to `.//:`

Comment: Oh great, thank you. If you want to make an answer out of your comment, I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are in your TEXINPUTS path then they should be found just referencing the local filename from tex so

```
TEXINPUTS=.//: luatex main-document
```

should find files in any level of subdirectory below the current directory

`.//` means all subdirectories of any depth below the current directory and trailing `:` means that this path segment is  added to the start of the standard TEXINPUTS Path, if you omit that then tex only looks in the local area and would not find `article.cls` etc.

This is assuming a bash or similar syntax for setting environment variables on the command line, would need to be adjusted for different command shells.

Rather than set this every time, you could set TEXINPUTS in your environment or in the local `texmf.cnf` configuration file.